# Do Jetson Orin Nano-like systems with 8GB RAM suffice to experiment with large language models?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to experiment with a platform that can run a virtual assistant (think e.g. https://mycroft.ai/) so to perform tasks like speech-to-text, conversations, text-to-speech, image segmentation and object detection (e.g. when fed with an RTSP stream).

I'm also curious about performing inference with large language models (LLMs), like those from Facebook Research's LLaMA (https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama).

Would a platform like Nvdia Jetson Orin Nano (8GB RAM) support LLMs inference, or would it still be underpowered, e.g. memory-constrained? What would be the specs I should aim for? I would use mainly pytorch as underlying framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sufficient for a 7B model.

You may refer to this link for details: https://nvidia-ai-iot.github.io/jetson-generative-ai-playground/tutorial_text-generation.html

[image]